The method or property WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync is not available on android, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?
I am trying to use KindeSdk to authenticate by expo application , but getting this error
Tried running this
npm install expo-web-browser
npx install-expo-modules@latest
but got
Run `npm audit` for details.
› Installing ios pods...
> pod install
Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
> pod install --repo-update
Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
Uncaught Error CocoaPodsError: Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
    at getImprovedPodInstallError (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\b99c464f4819196b\node_modules\install-expo-modules\build\index.js:34:664385)
    at CocoaPodsPackageManager.handleInstallErrorAsync (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\b99c464f4819196b\node_modules\install-expo-modules\build\index.js:34:659951)
    at CocoaPodsPackageManager.runInstallTypeCommandAsync (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\b99c464f4819196b\node_modules\install-expo-modules\build\index.js:34:661000)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async CocoaPodsPackageManager._installAsync (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\b99c464f4819196b\node_modules\install-expo-modules\build\index.js:34:660563)
    at async CocoaPodsPackageManager.handleInstallErrorAsync (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\b99c464f4819196b\node_modules\install-expo-modules\build\index.js:34:660149)
    at async CocoaPodsPackageManager.runInstallTypeCommandAsync (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\b99c464f4819196b\node_modules\install-expo-modules\build\index.js:34:660989)
    at async CocoaPodsPackageManager._installAsync (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\b99c464f4819196b\node_modules\install-expo-modules\build\index.js:34:660563)
    at async CocoaPodsPackageManager.installAsync (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\b99c464f4819196b\node_modules\install-expo-modules\build\index.js:34:659584)
    at async installPodsAsync (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\b99c464f4819196b\node_modules\install-expo-modules\build\index.js:34:764962) {
  code: 'COMMAND_FAILED',
  cause: Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
      at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
      at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    errno: -4058,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'spawn C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe',
    path: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe',
    spawnargs: [
      '/d',
      '/s',
      '/c',
      '"pod ^"install^" ^"--repo-update^" ^"--ansi^""'
    ],
    pid: undefined,
    output: [ '', '' ],
    stdout: '',
    stderr: '',
    status: null,
    signal: null
  },
  isPackageManagerError: true
}

Kindly suggest how will i be able to get around this
Or you can provide any other method to authenticate a user on react native

It looks like it's saying you don't have a C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe. Do you?

What environment is this? Is this a git bash or a WSL prompt? Are you somehow mixing Windows shell or PowerShell and some Linux-like environment?

Also had the same problem with WebBrowser.OpenBrowserAync, i Installed:
npm install expo-web-browser

However it wont work unless you rebuild while clearing cache
npx expo start -c

